# how to catch part of url string with javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I have a url string like this:
`example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1/subfolder1`

Is it possible to catch only the part after the = with javascript?
So the catched part should be this: `uploads/sfm/root/folder1/subfolder1`

Answer (score 2):

You may try this (Taken From MDN):

```
var getQueryVarByName = function (name)
{
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
};
```

Use:

```
var param = getQueryVarByName('dir'); // uploads/sfm/root/folder1/subfolder1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to split string at `=` and get second part

```js
var str = 'example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1/subfolder1';
var part = str.split('=')[1];
console.log(part);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.split()` to get it:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/hosane/1/edit?js,console)

```
var url = "example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1/subfolder1";

var s = url.split('=')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (Using the `.split()`):

```
function getFilePath(fullPath){
    return fullPath.split("dir=")[1];
}
```

Now call it the following way:

`getFilePath("example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1/subfolder1")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). If there are more parameters after dir regular expression should be more complicated.

```js
var url = 'example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1/subfolder1';
var regexp = /dir=([\w\W]*)/;
var matched = url.match(regexp);

document.body.innerHTML = matched[1];
```

Comment: oke this seems to be no problem. But now i also need to read the url string with javascript first. How can i do that?

Comment: use window.location.href

Comment: oke i alreadyhave that. Now one more question: i want bind th result to a php variable. How can i do that?

Comment: You can't. JavaScript runs in browser (at least in this case) and PHP on server, so you need to send query to server. But that is outside of scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

The part after question mark `?` is known as `window.location.search`. It is possible that you have than 1 parameter in this querystring. So safe solution should be like this:

```
//example.com/sfm?dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1/subfolder1&un=test&time=1234
function getPath(){
var query=window.location.search //?dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1/subfolder1&un=test&time=1234
   .replace(/^\?/,'') //dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1/subfolder1&un=test&time=1234
   .split('&'); //[dir=uploads/sfm/root/folder1/subfolder1, un=test, time=1234]
for(var i = 0, n = query.length;i < n;i++){
   var qs = query[i].split('=');
   if(qs.length == 2 && qs[0] == 'dir')
      return qs[1]; //if found
}//for
return null; // not found
}
```